# App freezes when I'm calling GetFolderFromPathAsync

Tags: uwp

My app completely freezes before it gets the chance to run even once. Here's the context:
I'm building a UWP app that will work with a user directory, monitor the files in it, and list them in a UI control. I added the directory to futureaccess list by creating a manual folder selection prompt. I also have a service class that's supposed to get me a list of files that reside in that directory. The app freezes as soon as I get to GetFolderFromPathAsync method. There's no exception or any kind of errors, the app attempts to start and just sits in the start up process indefinitely.
Here's the class where the method is called:

```cs
public class ReplayDirectoryManager
{
    public async static Task<List<StorageFile>> GetAllReplaysFromReplayDirectory()
    {
        string replayDirectoryPath = SettingsServices.SettingsService.Instance.ReplayFolderLocation;
        StorageFolder replayFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(replayDirectoryPath);

        return new List<StorageFile>(await replayFolder.GetFilesAsync());
    }
}
```

How do I get my code to work? Any suggestions?

Here's the code that I use to add the location to the futureaccess list

```cs
FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker();
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null)
{
    Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);
    ReplayFolderLocation = folder.Path;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remember the token returned by `FutureAccessList.Add(folder)` and then use it to get the *StorageFolder* by using it? Generally this is how it should be done, don't access files/folders by path in UWP.

Comment: how many files/folders in that path? try with an empty folder and tell us how it went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);` you can get the token.

You can use save the token to setting .

You can get the Folder by token

```
folder =  await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(token);
```

@Romasz Thx.

Comment: That was just a comment to give it a try and show better way, **BUT** it's not likely the solution for the problem - in that case OP should see *AccessException*, but his app freezes. He probably will need to provide more information.

Comment: @Romasz I find that it will freeze when I use to get a haze path that I readly have the access but I didnt use right way to get it .

Comment: @Romasz He use the FutureAccessList but have not save the token and he save the path that is not the official recommended method

Comment: Looks like this helped. I had another basic app that I was testing the code with without MVVM and it was working fine without the need for tokens. Weird.